# How do I interpret this regular expression?

Tags: regex

I read about the following article which talks about parsing html tag.. 
http://haacked.com/archive/2004/10/25/usingregularexpressionstomatchhtml.aspx/

I got confused about the usage of forward slash:

```
</?\w+\s+[\^>]*>
```

"Roughly Translated, this expression looks for the beginning tag and tag name, followed by some white-space and then anything that doesn’t end the tag."

Why doesn't < means left word boundary here?

What is /? I've searched the web. Some say / is special character, others do not even mention it.

Also how should I interpret [\^>]? any of \ ^ >? It does not make sense.

Could anyone explain this expression a little?

Comment: Why don't you explore this regex using a tool like Regex101?  Look here: https://regex101.com/r/lG6ZH0/1

Comment: By the way, there is nothing special about forward slash in regex, but you might have to escape it in some engines.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen Thanks, Tim. Great website and it explains well. Btw, some article says < and > are word boundary, and / is regex delimiter, not sure if they are true. It seems in this case, <> are plain literal and / is treated as special character.